# Can i create a background in the bottom another width and in the top another width

Tags: html, css

I have made a line with height 20px and width 100% but how can I achieve what it's in the photo this black line at the end it is like a slash.
Second photo what I am trying to achieve and first it is my actual design.

Below you can find a code.

```
<app-tabs tabAlignment="bottom" height="30px" width="150px" class="general" class="tabs">
  <app-tb style="background: #000000" title="Technical Matrix" topPadding="0px 0px 10px 0px" (click)="showMatrix()">
  </app-tb>
  <app-tb title="Technical Assignment" topPadding="0px 0px 10px 0px" (click)="showAssignment()" >
  </app-tb>
</app-tabs>

.tabs {
  background: #000000;
  width: calc(100% - 69px);
  margin-left: 27px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I could come up:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 97% 0%, 100% 25%, 0% 25%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 97% 0%, 100% 25%, 0% 25%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%);
```

You can mess with these values in the developer console to get it just right.

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/alecdesjardins/pen/JZLbMd), and here is the support for [clip-path](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path). I believe if it is not supported it just falls back to the original shape, which would not look bad.

You could always just create an image and use it as a background too!

Comment: thank you so much I have added your answer as accepted your saved me.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is probably better, but this may be more simple:

HTML

```
<div class="line-container">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="border"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.line-container {
  background-color: #fff;
 }
 .line, .border {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
 }
.line{
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  background-color: #000;
  height: 20px;
}
.border{
  border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noxb6e7c/12/

Comment: Much more simple, I like it!

Comment: Thanks man I like it to but both answers are good I dont know each one to make as accepted